# Remove a substring from a string based on its existence in perl

Tags: perl, grep, substring

I have an array - `@values` - containing elements like this.

```
abcd
ijk.*
alba
^defg
xyz.domain.example.com
```

I'm doing a check like this on the array:

```
foreach $val(@values)
{
    if(!`grep $val /tmp/list` && (!grep /$val/,@anotherlist )
    {
        #Perform an action;
    }
}
```

My `/tmp/list` and `@anotherlist` might/might not contain something like `xyz` or a regex value but not `xyz.domain.example.com`.  Here `domain` is of variable length.

So can you suggest a way to remove the `.domain.example.com` if I find it in the string?
I also maintain a list of domains in an array called `@domain`.

I'd prefer to have a solution with the operation inside my current if statement.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a basic string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

The index variable in a `for/foreach` loop is an alias to an array element. If you make a change to the index variable, then you are also making a change to the array element.

```
#Perform an action;
$val =~ s/\.domain\.example\.com//;
```

Comment: I thought of that solution but "domain" isn't the same for every element and even the length of "domain" is different in different array elements. I don't mind changing the array element itself.